# How to find similar text values within the same column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to find a way to highlight in the same column values which start with the same 3 characters:

| A |
| --- |
| Lorem Ipsum |
| Lorim |
| Esset |
| John |
| Johnathan |

On this example it would highlight all but Esset. I've done some research and found a Fuzzy match add-on but it does not work on Mac. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Also tried

- Match and Look up formulas without luck

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(LEFT(E8,3),LEFT(E:E,3),0)),"No Match",E8)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a rule based on `COUNTIFS`, `LEFT`, and a wildcard:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,LEFT(A2,3)&"*")>1
```

[image]